# Slight line top of the header

Tags: html, css, reactjs, tailwind-css

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="flex flex-row bg-purple_death h-14 m-0 p-0">
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-around items-center w-1/4">
          <button className=" border border-black hover:rounded">
            <BsJustify className="text-4xl" />
          </button>
          <div className="text-2xl">home</div>
        </div>
        <div className="w-full bg-grayish">
          <div className="searchbar"></div>
        </div>
        <div className="flex flex-row justify-around items-center w-1/4">
          <div className="text-2xl">Sign In</div>
          <div className="text-2xl">tr</div>
          <button className="w-20 h-10 hover:rounded-full bg-slate-400 text-2xl">
            dark
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Header;
```

my code is like this and output is:
[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jbwQv.png)

i tried m-0 and p-0 classes from tailwind on the parent div but nothing changed also tried to open project on other browsers but same output. How can i remove that little line ?

Comment: Could it be a border from the browser interfaces?

Comment: @Wongjn yeah i thought the same thing but its same on other browsers

Answer (score 0):

The line might be from the parent of the `Header` component.
Please check it out.

Comment: noo its not but i guess its browser's problem

Comment: I used Firefox and Chrome and didn't get that line, what browser are you using?

You can test your component in isolation here:

https://play.tailwindcss.com

p.s: write class instead of className